# Why am I getting an error in execute immediate command in oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle-11g-r2

I was just testing an anonymous code which I wrote for audit trail It's just a sample for test. However I am getting this error:

```
[Error] Execution (1: 1): ORA-00984: column not allowed here
ORA-06512: at line 29
```

Code:

```
DECLARE
    colName VARCHAR2(2000);
    colNewVal VARCHAR2(2000);
    sqlInsert VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
   colName := 'BOOK_NAME,AUTHOR,PUBLISHER,PUBLISH_YEAR';
   colNewVal := 'BOOK1,AUTH1,PUB1,2001';
   sqlInsert := 'INSERT INTO TBL_TRN_AUDIT_TRAIL_MASTER(';


   FOR cur_var IN (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (colName,'[^,]+',1,LEVEL) col_name FROM DUAL 
        CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR (colName,'[^,]+',1,LEVEL)IS NOT NULL)
    LOOP
        sqlInsert := sqlInsert || cur_var.col_name || ',';

    END LOOP;
    sqlInsert := SUBSTR(sqlInsert,1,INSTR(sqlInsert, ',', -1)-1);
    sqlInsert := sqlInsert || ')VALUES(';
    dbms_output.put_line (sqlInsert);
    FOR cur_var2 IN (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (colNewVal,'[^,]+',1,LEVEL) col_new_val FROM DUAL 
        CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR (colNewVal,'[^,]+',1,LEVEL)IS NOT NULL)
    LOOP
        sqlInsert := sqlInsert || cur_var2.col_new_val || ',';

    END LOOP;
    sqlInsert := SUBSTR(sqlInsert,1,INSTR(sqlInsert, ',', -1)-1);
    sqlInsert := sqlInsert || ')';
    dbms_output.put_line (sqlInsert);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlInsert;

END;
```

Line 29 is the execute immediate command.
Am I doing something wrong here??

Comment: Show us the output of `dbms_output.put_line (sqlInsert);`

Answer (score 1):

Actually i sort of got the problem here. In the Insert into statement I was not giving proper quotes for the Values which are VARCHAR2. Got sorted now.